# Selecting Item inside Child Arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I produce an array like this and I want to grab the first item in each of the child arrays:

```
arrayName = [[item1,item2,item3,item4],[item1,item2,item3,item4],[item1,item2,item3,item4]];
```

I'm trying this in a loop:

```
var num = arrayName.length;
for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
var title1 = arrayName[i][0];
}
```

But I get this on alert:

```
alert(title1);
=
[
[
[
```

I need:

```
alert(title1);
=
item1
item1
item1
```

I've tried using .nodeValue, .firstChild, etc but still not finding the answer. What's the right way?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(arrayName)`?

Comment: Are you working with a string?

Comment: are the items - item1, item2 etc variable names or should they be strings - `arrName = [["item1","item2"],["item1","item2"]];` - it works here - http://jsbin.com/ulasuv/1/;

Comment: sorry for not explaining enough - items are strings. Item 1 is a title and items 2,3 & 4 are numbers that relate to that title.

Example: ['TitleString',40,36,24],['TitleString',30,30,40]

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to show the actual code then, and also show how you are trying to use `alert()` (is it in the loop, or...)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = arrayName.length;
var title1 = new Array();
for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
title1.push(arrayName[i][0]);
}
console.log(title1);
```

Better?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer doesn't explain why the OP's code would be producing alerts that output `[`.

Comment: we don't know what those 'items' are.. they may even contain '['. Also that 'var title1' is being reset every loop iteration. AND he doesn't state precisely when the 'alert()' is executed. frankly I think the other answerer is just trying to get an edge...

Comment: That's true. But if they _do_ contain `[` as strings then your answer will have the same problem. The solution would be to fix the original array declaration to use `["item1", ...` or to fix the contents of those variables, not to change the `for` loop to put stuff into a second array.

Comment: Yes very true. But regardless of all this... 'title1' _at least_ should be declared outside the loop. Indeed his copy of the alert output is perplexing.

Comment: Yes, and `i` should be declared with `var` too. It would be helpful if the OP had included their use of `alert()` in the main code block. I can only assume they've put it inside the loop if they're getting three brackets as output, but basically they've left us to guess at what they're doing...

Answer (score 0):

You can the use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
var arrayName = [[item1,item2,item3,item4],[item1,item2,item3,item4],[item1,item2,item3,item4]];

var childrenArray = arrayName.map(function(childArray) { return childArray[0]; });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c78jS/)

Comment: But if the code shown in the question doesn't work this wouldn't work either would it?

Comment: I assume item1, item2, etc. are variables. In my example, I've used strings  
@d'alar'cop: no, your solution is fine too

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was how the array was being created. Each child array was being pushed into this array but it was detecting the [ as part of the string. Changing this push has solved my problem. Thanks for your input though :)